# Connection cannot be established between Node.js 16.20 version and MySQL 5.7.42

Tags: mysql, node.js

Our website is developed using Node.js, specifically version 16.20. However, we are experiencing connection issues between our website and MySQL version 5.7.42 on our hosting environment using the provided code:

```
const options = {
  host: 'localhost',
  user: '...',
  password: '...',
  database: '...',
  port: 3306
}
```

Interestingly, we can establish a connection to a MySQL version 8.0.32 on another hosting provider, indicating that there is no issue with the code itself. Despite conducting extensive research, we have been unable to find a solution. When contacting our hosting provider, they assure us that there are no problems with their MySQL servers. Additionally, we can access MySQL successfully through phpMyAdmin. The only issue we encounter is the inability to establish a connection to MySQL using the aforementioned code on our website.

Here is the error message we receive:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
    at PromisePool.query (/home/websitename/nodevenv/websitename/16/lib/node_modules/express-mysql-session/node_modules/mysql2/promise.js:351:22)
    at /home/websitename/nodevenv/websitename/16/lib/node_modules/express-mysql-session/index.js:384:30
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at MySQLStore.query (/home/websitename/nodevenv/websitename/16/lib/node_modules/express-mysql-session/index.js:381:10)
    at /home/websitename/nodevenv/websitename/16/lib/node_modules/express-mysql-session/index.js:170:16
```

We appreciate any assistance in resolving this issue.

I suggested opening MySQL for remote connections and trying to access it using the IP address, but it still didn't work. Now the only thing that comes to mind is that it might be due to the MySQL version being 5.7.42, but I'm not sure, of course.

Comment: first check the mysql error log, it would show you if there is a problem with the server and on which port it runs